# SqlDataAdapter type or namespace not found

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, uwp

I want to connect my SQL Server database from my UWP app, but I keep getting the error that the `SqlDataAdapter` type or namespace not found and that my datagrid does not have a source. I added the `using System.Data.SqlClient` and `using System.Data;` statements.

```
string cs = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Artist;Integrated Security=True";

SqlConnection con;
SqlDataAdapter adapt;
DataTable dt;

//frmSearch Load Event   
private void frmSearch_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(cs);
    con.Open();

    adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from ArtistTable", con);
    dt = new DataTable();
    adapt.Fill(dt);

    ArtistGV.DataSource = dt;
    con.Close();
}

private void txtsearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(cs);
    con.Open();

    adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from ArtistTable where ArtistName like '" + txtsearch.Text + "%'", con);
    dt = new DataTable();
    adapt.Fill(dt);

    ArtistGV.DataSource = dt;
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Make sure you add a reference to System.Data in your project.

Comment: it is added, Its just at the SqlDataadapter and at the ArtistGV.DataSource I get the error

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Unrelated tips: `SqlConnection` and `SqlDataAdapter` are both `IDisposable` so each should be in a `using` block. Once you've done that, you don't need the Close, since the implicit Dispose will call that as it exits the using block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app's must target version and min version must be at least Fall Creators Update (16299) to be able to use `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace. You can check the [requirement info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases). You can change the targeting in the project's **Properties** (right-click the project node in **Solution Explorer**).

[image: Fall creators update targeting]

Also in case `ArtistGV` is a `GridView`, you need to use `ItemsSource` property instead of `DataSource`. If you rather want to create a tabular data grid, use 
the [`DataGrid` control in the Windows Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid). That matches more closely to the `DataGrid` in WPF and ASP.NET.

Comment: thanks. Partially solved my problem. I now only have an error on the ArtistGV.Datasource= dt; line. It says Gridview does not contain a definition for DatSource

Comment: I have updated my answer, you probably want to rather use the `DataGrid` control from Windows Community Toolkit.

Comment: Thank you. solved that.  any idea on why my data is not showing?

Comment: Are you using `DataGrid`? To display in `GridView` you would have to create a `ItemTemplate` first, otherwise you will just get a simple `type.ToString()` content. It may be better to close this question as resolved and create a new question for this as it is a different problem now.

Comment: Let me know when you post the question, I will take a look :-)

Comment: thanks I will do. Sorry im still new to all of this.

Comment: No problem, that's why we are here :-)

Comment: Question is posted.